# pyspark window function with filter

Tags: pyspark, filtering

I have the following DataFrame with columns: `["id", "timestamp", "x", "y"]`:

```python
+---+----------+---+---+
| id| timestamp|  x|  y|
+---+----------+---+---+
|  0|1443489380|100|  1|
|  0|1443489390|200|  0|
|  0|1443489400|300|  0|
|  1|1443489410|400|  1|
|  1|1443489550|100|  1|
|  2|1443489560|600|  0|
|  2|1443489570|200|  0|
|  2|1443489580|700|  1|
+---+----------+---+---+
```

I have defined the following `Window`:

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window
w = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("timestamp")
```

I would like to extract only the first and last row of data in the window `w`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You need [`pyspark.sql.functions.first()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first) and [`pyspark.sql.functions.last()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.last). `df.select(first('id').over(w).alias('id'), ....)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the first and last values on the same row, one way is to use [`pyspark.sql.functions.first()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.first):

```python
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import first

w1 = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("timestamp")
w2 = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(f.col("timestamp").desc())  # sort desc

df.select(
        "id",
        *([first(c).over(w1).alias("first_" + c) for c in df.columns if c != "id"] +
          [first(c).over(w2).alias("last_" + c) for c in df.columns if c != "id"])
    )\
    .distinct()\
    .show()
#+---+---------------+-------+-------+--------------+------+------+
#| id|first_timestamp|first_x|first_y|last_timestamp|last_x|last_y|
#+---+---------------+-------+-------+--------------+------+------+
#|  0|     1443489380|    100|      1|    1443489400|   300|     0|
#|  1|     1443489410|    400|      1|    1443489550|   100|     1|
#|  2|     1443489560|    600|      0|    1443489580|   700|     1|
#+---+---------------+-------+-------+--------------+------+------+
```